# How to return authRequired and WL.Server.invokeHttp value to client side using web services in Adapter based authentication with worklight?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ibm-mobilefirst

Edit : I am using Adapter based authentication with worklight and angularJs. on click of login button i'm calling **submitLogin** procedure and pass the username and password in parameter as mention below. my query is after invocation of adapter how i'll return the authRequired value and WL.Server.invokeHttp(input) response simultaneously to the client side. i also mention challenge handler for authentication in login services code

**adapter code:**

```
function submitLogin(username, password){
    WL.Logger.debug("username: "+username);
    var payload = {
            "Header": {
                "header": {
                    "myschemeName": "",
                    "myserviceVersion": "0.00",
                   "myinternalId": "",
                    "myexternalId": "",
                    "mysource": "web",
                    "mydestination": "test",
                    "myuserId": ""
                }
            },
            "Body": {
                "login": {
                    "username": username,
                    "password": password
                }
            }
        }
    var input = {
        method : 'post',
        returnedContentType : 'jsonp',
        path: '/mywebservices/login',
        headers : {
            'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip,deflate',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: { 
                    'contentType' : 'application/json',         
                    'content' : payload
                }
    };

    return {authRequired: false, WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);};
}
```

**login services:**

```
angular.module('my.services')
       .factory('loginServices', function($http, $q, $rootScope) {
           'use strict';

            //worklight
            var realm = "AdapterAuthRealm";
            var securityTest = "Master-Password";
            //offline
            var offlineAuthed = false;
            var tempUser = {};
            //user object
            var userObj = {};
            //login popup
            userObj.dialog = false;
            //login error message
            userObj.authError = "";
            //logged in boolean
            userObj.loggedIn = null;

            var defunct = null;

            //change handler
            var ch = WL.Client.createChallengeHandler(securityTest);

            //first response after protected call
            ch.isCustomResponse = function(response){ 
                console.log("challenge handler -- isCustomResponse");
                if (!response || !response.responseJSON || response.responseText === null) {
                    return false;
                }
                if (typeof(response.responseJSON.authRequired) !== 'undefined'){
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            };

            //when isCustomResponse returns true
            ch.handleChallenge = function(response){ 
                console.log("challenge handler -- handleChallenge");
                var err = response.responseJSON.errorMessage;
                var req = (String(response.responseJSON.authRequired) == "true");
                if (!req){ //successful login request
                    console.log("-> login success!");
                    //create offline auth credentials
                    createOfflineAuth();
                    //call the success function of initial adapter call 
                    //ch.submitSuccess();
                } 
                //error message
                userObj.authError = "";
                if (err != null){
                    userObj.authError = "* " + err;
                }
                //login boolean
                userObj.loggedIn = !req;
                //show login popup
                userObj.dialog = req;
                //update scope
                $rootScope.$apply();
                //resolve original function if it exists
                if (defunct != null){
                 defunct.resolve(userObj.loggedIn);
                }
            };

            //**  Offline  **//
            //check if user is online
            function checkOnline(){
                var def = $q.defer();
                WL.Client.connect({
                    onSuccess: function(){
                        console.log("** User is online!");
                        def.resolve(true);

                    },
                    onFailure: function(){
                        console.log("** User is offline!");
                        def.resolve(false);
                    },
                    timeout: 1000
                });
                return def.promise;
            }

            //creates an offline authentication object
            function createOfflineAuth(){
                console.log("creating offline auth");
                //encrypt the user object
                var encyptedUser = md5(angular.toJson(tempUser));
                //save to local storage
                localStorage.setItem(tempUser.username, encyptedUser);
                //clear tempUser
                tempUser = {};
            }

            //offline login
            function offlineLogin(){
                userObj.authError = "";
                //encrypt the tempuser object
                var match = md5(angular.toJson(tempUser));
                var savedAuth = localStorage.getItem(tempUser.username);
                //check if matching the saved one
                offlineAuthed = (savedAuth == match);
                console.log("Login successfull: " + offlineAuthed);
                //error - mismach
                if (!offlineAuthed){
                    userObj.authError = "* Wrong login details.";
                }
                //error - if the user has never authenticated with the server
                if (savedAuth == null){
                    userObj.authError = "* You have to go online first.";
                }
                //login boolean
                userObj.loggedIn = offlineAuthed;
                //show login popup
                userObj.dialog = !offlineAuthed;
                return offlineAuthed;
            }


            //-- APIS to the rest of the app --//

            return {

                getUser: function(){
                    return userObj;

                },

                initUser: function () {
                    console.log("-> getting user state data");
                    var def = $q.defer();
                    checkOnline().then(function (onl){
                        if (onl){ //online
                            WL.Client.updateUserInfo({onSuccess: function(){    
                                userObj.loggedIn = WL.Client.isUserAuthenticated(realm);
                                def.resolve();
                            }});
                        } else { //offline
                            userObj.loggedIn = false;
                            def.resolve();
                        }
                    });
                    return def.promise;
                },

                checkUser: function () {
                    var def = $q.defer();
                    checkOnline().then(function (onl){
                        if (onl){ //online
                            userObj.loggedIn = WL.Client.isUserAuthenticated(realm);
                        } else { //offline
                            userObj.loggedIn = offlineAuthed;
                        }
                        userObj.dialog = !userObj.loggedIn;
                        //check success
                        if (!userObj.loggedIn){
                            //save the deferred for challengehandler
                            defunct = def;
                        } else {
                            //resolve
                            def.resolve(true);
                        }
                    });
                    return def.promise;
                },

                login: function (user,pass){
                    //promise
                    var logindef = $q.defer();
                    //tempuser
                    tempUser = {username:user, password:pass};
                    userObj.user = user;
                    checkOnline().then(function (onl){
                    if (onl){ //online
                            console.log("attempting online login");
                            var options = {
                                parameters:[user, pass],    
                                adapter:"myAdapter",
                                procedure:"submitLogin"
                            };
                            ch.submitAdapterAuthentication(options,{
                                onSuccess: function(){
                                    console.log("-> submitAdapterAuthentication onSuccess!");
                                    //update user info, as somehow isUserAuthenticated return false without it
                                    WL.Client.updateUserInfo({onSuccess: function(){    
                                        //return promise
                                        logindef.resolve(true);
                                    }});


                                    }
                            });
                    } else { //offline
                            console.log("attempting offline login");
                            logindef.resolve(offlineLogin());
                        }
                    });
                    return logindef.promise;
                }
            };
        });
```

Comment: what error do you get ? what is not working ? could you be more precise ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am trying to decrypt your question. It's not clear at all.

However there is already one thing that jumps out.
In your adapter you finished with:

`return {authRequired: false, WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);};`

You saying authRequired false even before checking if the credentials are valid?
You are supposed to parse the content of the results of `WL.Server.invokeHttp(input)` inside the adapter, decide if the credentials are valid.

If they are valid use `setActiveUser` before returning `authRequired` `false`.
Don't return the content of `WL.Server.invokeHttp(input)` to the client. This is meant for the adapter to parse.

See this tutorial: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/authentication-security/adapter-based-authentication/